# Input not recognised from touchpad

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I am trying to extend this [Roll-a-Ball tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) to include a timer and allow the user to try again by tapping the touchpad whether they win or run out of time.

This works as expected if the time runs out (`// case A` below) but not if the player wins (`// case B` below), where the tap does not seem to be recognised. The end message appears in both cases so it is definitely reaching those parts but I'm guessing that the program is not reaching the section with the comment `// reset on tap` but am not certain.

Any ideas appreciated.

My `PlayerController` script:

```
void Start ()
{
    timeLeft = 5;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    winText.text = "";
    SetCountText ();
}
void Update()
{
    if (!gameOver) {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    timerText.text = timeLeft.ToString ("0.00");
    if(timeLeft < 0) {
        winner = false;
        GameOver(winner);
    }
}
void GameOver(bool winner)
{
    gameOver = true;
    timerText.text = "-- --";
    string tryAgainString = "Tap the touch pad to try again.";
    if (!winner) { // case A
        winText.text = "Time's up.\n" + tryAgainString;
    }
    if (winner) { // case B
        winText.text = "Well played!\n" + tryAgainString;
    }
    // reset on tap
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
} 
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y"); 
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);    
    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up")){
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText ();
        if (!gameOver) {
            timeLeft += 3;
        }
    }
}   
void SetCountText ()
{
    if (!gameOver) {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
    }
    if (count >= 12) {
        winner = true;
        GameOver(winner);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Debug.Log in SetCountText method, and output the value of count count. You are probably never hitting the 12 point mark.
Make sure all your collectibles have the tag " Pick Up".

**Update**
You should listen for player input in `Update` method. `FixedUpdate` and any other functions that execute as part of Fixed Update will miss the player input if it happens between two `FixedUpdate` calls.

So change your `Update` and `GameOver` method as follows:

```
void Update() {
    if (gameOver) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Application.LoadLevel(0);
        }
    } else {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = timeLeft.ToString("0.00");
        if (timeLeft < 0) {
            winner = false;
            GameOver(winner);
        }

    }

}
void GameOver(bool winner) {
    gameOver = true;
    timerText.text = "-- --";
    string tryAgainString = "Tap the touch pad to try again.";
    if (!winner) { // case A
        winText.text = "Time's up.\n" + tryAgainString;
    }
    if (winner) { // case B
        winText.text = "Well played!\n" + tryAgainString;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is definitely reaching 12 as the message `Well Played..` is displayed correctly.

Comment: I see the problem. You should always check for player input in Update. You are checking for mouse click in OnTirggerEnter>SetCountText->GameOver(). So, you are basically listening for input in a FixedUpdate call. I will edit the answer with a solution in a minute.